# Change resolution of converted images using Sphinx ImageMagick extension sphinx.ext.imgconverter

Tags: pdf, svg, imagemagick, latex, python-sphinx

We are using Python-Sphinx to build our end user manuals.

In order to automatically convert our assorted graphic file formats like we are using the Sphinx Extension `sphinx.ext.imgconverter`, which utilizes ImageMagick to convert our graphic file formats to graphic formats, which the given build target can understand.

For detailed information see: [sphinx.ext.imgconverter](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/imgconverter.html)

Unfortunately, the output of the converted images does not satisfy our needs. A main issue is the low resolution of the converted images, which gives pixelated outcomes.

Therefore I included the following line to my `conf.py`:

```
image_converter_args=["-density 300"]
```

Now, the build process fails and leaves me with the following error message.

```
Extension error:
convert exited with error:
[stderr]
magick.exe: unrecognized option `-density 300' at CLI arg 1 @ fatal/magick-cli.c/ProcessCommandOptions/428.
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Does this work? `image_converter_args=["convert -density 300"]` (running `convert` as a subcommand of `magick`).

Comment: @mzjn: It now says: `unable to open image 'convert -density 300'` and still fails.

Comment: I haven't used ImageMagick very much and the documentation is confusing. According to https://imagemagick.org/script/magick.php, `magick` does recognize the `-density` option.

Comment: @mzjn: I know, but obviously it just not working. Maybe there is a problem how to use the image_converter_args. `magick.exe -density 300 in.svg out.pdf` works without any problems.

Comment: The error message indicates that you did not supply an input image. Try omitting `convert` from the args. Also provide the path to `convert` for `image_converter`. Also ensure you have the latest IM and Sphinx installed (IM support had a bug in Sphinx < 1.7). Suggest searching the [Sphinx issue tracker](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/search?q=sphinx.ext.imgconverter&type=Issues), and perhaps contact the author of the extension for correct usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments should be a list.

```
image_converter_args=["-density", "300"]
```

Where "-density" is the operator argument, and "300" is the value argument.

Comment: Many thanks for your fast reply. Now everythings works as desired. Would have been nice, if the documentation of this extension would have been a little bit more verbose. :-)